# How to use a parameter from first loop in the second loop?

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to insert array data to database. There are parent_array and child_arrays.

```
$arr_parent    = ['Apple','Banana','Grape'];        //parent_array
$arr_child_par = ['Price','Stock','Date_Stocked'];  //first child array ex.
$arr_child_val = ['1000','200','2012-05-05'];       //second child array ex.
```

The HTML:

```
<input type='text' name='arr_parent[]' class='arr_parent' value='"+$('#fruit').val()+"' />    //Each table row has one this textbox

<input type='text' name='arr_child_par[]' class='arr_child_par' value='Price' />    //Each table row has multiple of these textboxes

<input type='text' name='arr_child_val[]' class='arr_child_val' value='1000' />    //Each table row has multiple of these textboxes
```

Now, the rule are like this:

- Every `$arr_child_par` length and value is different depending on it's `$arr_parent`
- Every `$arr_child_val` length is the same as `$arr_child_par`

In the end, this is the table structure of desired output:

t_fruit

```
NO     FRUIT
 1      Apple
 2     Banana
 3      Grape
```

t_fruit_d

```
NO      FRUIT       PARAMETER      PARAMETER_VALUE
 1      Apple           Price                 1000
 2      Apple           Stock                  300
 3      Banana          Stock                  400
 4      Banana       Supplier                 John
 5      Banana   Date_Stocked          '2018-02-14'
 6       Grape          Price                 3000
```

How to get the fruit in the `$arr_parent` and use it on the `$arr_child_par` ?

Comment: why don't you build your array structure that way that you can use it in first place? Where does the data come from? Right now the arrays are not connected in any way.

Comment: @Jeff Dynamic HTML table

Comment: How to connect it? I'll post the html

Comment: Perhaps someone can show me the proper array in the PHP and the HTML as well

Answer (score 0):

It look's like you have 3 tables? Fruit, Parameter and Parameter value.
So instead of using the "label" of a parameter, you should probably use Foreign Key
So it give something like that :

```
Table FRUIT
NO     label
 1      Apple
 2     Banana
 3      Grape

Table PARAM
NO     label    
 1      Price   
 2      Stock             
 3      Supplier
 4      Date_Stocked
 etc

Table PARAM_VAL
NO     FRUIT_ID      PARAM_ID      PARAM_VAL
 1     1             1             1000
 2     1             2             300
 3     2             2             400
 4     2             3             "John"
```

With this structure, you can store it and to build an Object "fruit_d" but this solution is pretty ugly in PHP and can be really heavy with a lot of data... So I recommand to use SQL JOIN instead to directly build your `fruit_d` in php.

Answer (score 0):

schema

```
CREATE TABLE fruits (
    fruit_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    fruit VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
    );

CREATE TABLE params (
    param_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    fruit_id INT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (fruit_id) REFERENCES fruit (fruit_id)
);

CREATE TABLE params_val (
    param_val_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    fruit_id INT NOT NULL,
    param_id INT,
    FOREIGN KEY (fruit_id) REFERENCES fruits (fruit_id)
    FOREIGN KEY (param_id) REFERENCES params (param_id)
);
```

php update and join

```
<?php 
//connect and check
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'mydb');
if (!$con) { exit(); }

// post and serialize
$fruit = implode("'","'", $_POST['arr_parent'] );
$param = implode("'","'", $_POST['arr_child_par'] );
$param_val = implode("'","'", $_POST['arr_child_val'] );

//db insert
$fruit_insert = "INSERT INTO fruits (label) VALUES ('.$fruit.')";
$param_insert = "INSERT INTO param (label) VALUES ('.$param.')";
$param_val_insert = "INSERT INTO param_val (label) VALUES ('.$param_val.')";

//join
$sql = "SELECT fruit, parameter, parameter_val
        FROM fruits
            LEFT OUTER JOIN params ON fruits.fruit_id = params.fruit_id
            INNER JOIN params_val ON params.param_id = params_val.param_id";

$result = mysql_query($sql);
?>
```

thats the idea..